# weird CORS problem caused by custom config for fetch

Tags: javascript, html, http, cors

I was writing a little wrapper for `fetch` method in JavaScript (I am very aware of libs like Axios that can do the same thing). I got the idea from [a blog post](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/replace-axios-with-a-simple-custom-fetch-wrapper)

My code looks like this

```js
async function apiCall(
  endpoint,
  { data, headers: customHeaders, ...customConfig } = {}
) {
  console.log("endpoint", endpoint);
  const config = {
    method: data ? "POST" : "GET",
    body: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : undefined,
    headers: {
      "content-type": data ? "application/json" : undefined,
      ...customHeaders
    },
    ...customConfig
  };

  return window.fetch(endpoint, config).then(async (response) => {
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.json();
    } else {
      // By default, window.fetch will only reject a promise if the actual request itself failed (network error), not if it returned a "Client error response".
      const error = await response
        .json()
        .catch(() => new Error("invalid json"));
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  });
}

export function requestMovies(query) {
  const endpoint = `${apiULR}?apikey=${API_KEY}&s=${encodeURIComponent(query)}`;

  return apiCall(endpoint);
}
```

However, I encountered `TypeError Failed to fetch` which I believed is caused by CORS.

If I take out `config` from `window.fetch` as in

```js
async function apiCall(
  endpoint,
  { data, headers: customHeaders, ...customConfig } = {}
) {
  return window.fetch(endpoint).then(async (response) => {
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.json();
    } else {
      // By default, window.fetch will only reject a promise if the actual request itself failed (network error), not if it returned a "Client error response".
      const error = await response
        .json()
        .catch(() => new Error("invalid json"));
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  });
}
```

The problem would be gone. Not sure which part exactly triggered this CORS problem...

Here is a live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-saha-4c2bh?file=/src/index.js

Comment: This is expected because with `headers: { "content-type": data ? "application/json" : undefined, ...customHeaders }`, the code shown in the question causes a `content-type` request header to be added to the request — which results in the browser logging the error *“Access to fetch at '`https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=[apikey]&s=war`' from origin '`https://4c2bh.csb.app`' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.”*. So `https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey` doesn’t allow requests with a content-type header

Answer (score -1):

follow the `data` not given path:

1. the ternary goes into the false case
2. `headers` gets an entry `content-type: undefined`
3. the request gets this header added
4. request is rejected by api because it contains a content-type header (probably with the string `'undefined'` in it)

Solution: Dont use a ternary here, and replace it with an `if`, to get rid of the `undefined` entry.
Also: read up on differences between null, undefined values and "has own property" in javascript objects

Comment: I know how ternary works and I know `content-type: undefined` is added as a result. What I don't understand is why is that `content-type: undefined` caused the cors problem.

Comment: because it says so in the error message apparently? quoting your comment: "has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response"